# How to check if the provided information to AMQPStreamConnection are valid in RabbitMQ?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I wrote a custom error logging method and I'm implementing it where things could go wrong. For RabbitMQ however, it's not clear for me how to check for an error. This is my code

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$errorServiceObject = new ErrorService();
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();
if(!isset($channel))
{
    $errorServiceObject->LogError('RabbitMQ error.', 'Could not initiate a RabbitMQ connection.');
    exit();
}
```

The way I do it at the moment is bad because it only checks whether the variable `$channel` is set or when the connection is simply not initiated correctly. I would like to check whether the `new AMQPStreamConnection` information are valid or not. Consider this example where I do this

`$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhostWithATypo', 5444, 'guest', 'guest'); //wrong hostname and wrong port number`. What would I need to put in the if statement to trigger the error handeling function?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`php-amqplib`](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib), take a look at the documentation. There are some code snippets that illustrate how `new AMQPStreamConnection` throws exceptions. See https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib#connection-recovery.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at them but wasn't sure if an/these exception(s) would work in this case?

Comment: Would I still be able to use my custom made method? If you could provide an example in my case that would be great!